# Angular update 8 to 9: NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy, angular-upgrade

I've searching for an answer but could not find any solution that fix the issue.

I have updated version of Angular from version 8 to version 9. Everything worked fine on 8 but after update app does not compile due to error

```
src/app/groups/groups.module.ts:45:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors
```

But this module doe not contain any errors. It's clean as it was in version 8 when it worked.
I tried different things:

1. remove node_modules and re-install packages
2. close terminal and re-open
3. close editor(*VSC*) and re-open
4. clean cache `npm cache clean` with and without `--force` flag
5. `"importHelpers": true,` in tsconfig.json file

Components are in declarations, modules in imports, everything is correct and `groups.module.ts` shows error but
[file does not contain any errors inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8Sm.png).
Modules are imported correctly as well (i.e. `import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';` when in version 8 was `import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';` so regarding those things it is as it's been.

The only thing that helped was disabling Ivy with:
`"angularCompilerOptions": {"enableIvy": false }` but it's pointless to update application if I cannot use improvements.

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies":{
"@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "~0.901.15",
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.0.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/material": "^9.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
"@ngrx/effects": "^8.1.0",
"@ngrx/schematics": "^8.1.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.1.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.1.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"npm": "^6.12.0",
"resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"webpack": "^4.46.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.3",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
 },

"devDependencies":{
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
"@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.1.13",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "3.8.3"
 }
```

Nothing what I've found in internet && stackoverflow did not bring any solution aparat from disabling Ivy which I want to avoid.

What else should I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you scroll up in the terminal log to check which errors are also thrown? This error means that one of the imported angular components, modules,  ... or the module itself might have an error.

Comment: Yes indeed this error doesn't say anything more useful than "there is some error inside the subtree of that module". This can also happen if you place a Component as an import instead of the module providing that component by accident.

Comment: @MehyarSawas I have scrolled. No other errors apart from this mentioned.

Comment: @Malte I guess that if such situation arises it would not compile in version 8 as well and in Angular 8 worked fine.

Comment: Ok, then the best is to create a stackblitz example from your project to make it easier investigate and provide you a solution

Comment: What sometimes helps me. I just start removing each import from the module class and recompile and recheck until I figure it out which import causes the problem.

Comment: @MehyarSawas it's immposible to recreate this in stackblitz unfortunately and removing imports one by one also nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already made sure that your are not importing any of the components in the `declarations` array in another module?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that everything was in right place.

Comment: Including the `GroupsRoutingModule`? You can't declare the same components in the routing modules and in the module containing the routing module.